# Replace word after specific key in TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, tinymce

Good evening,

I have a word, typed after @ - tag:

*Hello, @Anto*

How Could I replace everything, that comes after @ to my own text?

And maybe you know, how ro resolve my question with jQuery Autocomplete:

[jQuery remote autocomplete with hashtags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14509278/jquery-remote-autocomplete-with-hashtags)

Thanks

Update:

Now I'm inserting text after current caret position, but with it I cant' make links:

```
content = (this.name).substring(state.length-1,(this.name).length);
                                            ed.selection.setContent(content + "|" + this.param);
```

Comment: @DaveJarvis `content = (this.name).substring(state.length-1,(this.name).length);
              ed.selection.setContent(content + "|" + this.param);`  It helps me to insert text after current caret position

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you will need to use the execCommand `mceInsertContent`.
See the full list of possible commands here: http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:valid_children